# Can I unzip WordPress folder directly into htdocs folder?

Tags: wordpress

Can I unzip WordPress folder directly into htdocs folder without creating WordPress folder in it?

Answer (score 0):

To unzip wordpress.zip inside htdocs folder, one blank folder should be there. 
So first create blank folder that unzip wordpress.zip inside that folder.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, the wordpress files should be installed in the DocumentRoot for the website which I think in your case is the htdocs folder.

When you unzip it it will unzip with a wordpress folder, just move the contents of the folder up a level and remove the wordpress directory.

You just need to configure your `wp-config.php` file with the relevant access details for the database connection